# Click Button on Webpage via VBScript?

Tags: button, vbscript, click, bots

I am working on making a bot with VBScript, that opens a webpage in Internet Explorer and clicks a button. I have opening the page down, but I don't know how to click the button. I have the element. I want to do something like this:

```
browser.Document.All("Button_Name").Click()
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question… The code you suggested is correct, so if that isn't working you'll need to elaborate on the specific problem if you want help troubleshooting.

Comment: In addition to Tmdean, try to look up what the methods `GetElementById()` and `GetElementsByName()` do. They could be usefull.

Answer (score 2):

```
'Search Google
Dim objWshShell,IE,searchStr

Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
searchStr = InputBox("Search")

With IE
  .Visible = True
  .Navigate "http://www.google.com"

'Wait for Browser
  Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
  .Document.getElementsByName("q").Item(0).Value = searchStr
  .Document.getElementsByName("btnK").Item(0).Click
End With
```